Can VS Code cpptools suggest the name of a member function when writing a separate definition?
URL : https://gifyu.com/image/SA9NI
After typed first keyword and typing another character suggestion box is not popup.
Example:
class Person{

public:

void showInfo();

};

//Giving Definition

void Person::showInfo(){}

Popup suggestion when typing void but after that it does not suggestion or popup for typing anything like Person [No Suggestion]
I need to do it manully to show suggestion by pressing shortcut key [my case ctrl+space].
when i typed wrong keyword suppose viod then typed anything suggestion box will opened.
I installed c/c++ extension also microsoft all intellisense enabled quickSuggestion as well.
I tried everything but i didn't get it what's wrong.I also tried visual studio same issue there. But in clion from jetbrains show suggestion.

I use Clangd instead of the official C++ extension, and it does autocomplete correctly in this case.

It'd be nice if cpptools did what you're asking for, but if the goal is to write a definition of a declared member function, you can just use the "create definition" code action (#664). Put the caret in the symbol name for the declaration, and then open the quick fix menu with ctrl/cmd+., or running Quick Fix... in the command palette, and then select that code action. Note that you can also bind specific code actions to keyboard shortcuts.
